# If a User is not Logged In and Click on a Button First They Must Be Logged In to Continue? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I've setup a button Now i wanted when a user clicks on the button if they are already login then can click on the button but if they are not logged and when clicks on the button the button should redirect to the login In page?

```
<?php

function your_function( $user_login, $user ) 
{
    // your code
}

add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Will help.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <a href="specific_action">Your Label</a>
    <?php
} else { ?>
    <a href="login_page_url">Your Label</a>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I wanted to target a Single button how i can do that

Comment: Do you want to check on the button click if the user is logged in or not and then proceed?

Comment: Yes, When user clicks on the button if they are not logged in they will redirect to the login page but if they are logged in then they continue

Comment: Then you'll need to check it using Ajax.

Comment: As it's not described what that *continue* does so I am assuming, you want and JS action on as **continue** in that case, you can add a class on a button based on the `is_user_logged_in()` status, and on that css class you can trigger your JS event, when class won't there, action won't trigger and you'll be redirected to another page as the default behavior of `<a>` tag.